# can't convert Symbol into Integer in f.select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the search page, i have a dropdown i.e populating from the `students` table. And when I select a value from dropdown and after click on search button the selected value of dropdown is lost, below is the code of dropdown:

```
<%= form_for :search, :url => { :method => :get, :action => :search } do |f| %>
    <table>
     <tr>
        <td align="center">
           <%= f.select(:Interest,options_from_collection_for_select(@students, "id", "student_mentor_subjects"), {},:id => "DDL_Students", :style => "width:160px;") %>
         </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
           <div class="button">
               <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" class="buttonSearch">
           </div>
        </td>
     </tr>   
    </table>
<% end %>
```

Then after google, I put this `params[:search][:Interest] || @students.id` in my code

```
<%= form_for :search, :url => { :method => :get, :action => :search } do |f| %>
        <table>
         <tr>
            <td align="center">
               <%= f.select(:Interest,options_from_collection_for_select(@students, "id", "student_mentor_subjects", params[:search][:Interest] || @students.id), {},:id => "DDL_Students", :style => "width:160px;") %>
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <div class="button">
                   <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" class="buttonSearch">
               </div>
            </td>
         </tr>   
        </table>
    <% end %>
```

But by using above code I am getting an error below:

```
can't convert Symbol into Integer
```

below is the schema of "students" table:

```
id | student_mentor_subjects
1  | abc
2  | def
3  | ijk
```

How do i resolve this. Kindly suggest me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So you want to be able to post the search and keep the value you selected previously?

Try this:

```
<%= f.select(:Interest,options_from_collection_for_select(@students, "id", "student_mentor_subjects"), {}, :selected => params[:search], :id => "DDL_Students", :style => "width:160px;") %>
```

or

```
<%= f.select(:Interest,options_from_collection_for_select(@students, "id", "student_mentor_subjects"), {}, :selected => params[:search][:Interest], :id => "DDL_Students", :style => "width:160px;") %>
```

The second one is a complete guess,

Comment: the first one I was already try but its not giving me the dropdown selected value into a controllers page. and second one giving me error "can't convert Symbol into Integer"